# Netbeans: Could I use Apache Felix for a home-maintained repo of Java libs?

Tags: java, netbeans, module, repository

I'm using Netbeans. Often I need to specify own libraries, used by my
projects. It is very unhandy to maintain them across multiple workspaces.

As far as I understand correctly, Apache Felix, an implementation of OSGI's
module system, could manage such libraries *(provide versioning,
automatic dependency resolvability, ...)*

If this is correct, is there a somehow straightforward way to integrate
Apache Felix into Netbeans?

*BTW: Can't wait for Jigsaw module system in Java 7*

Comment: Is there any reason you don't like maven?

Comment: Maven is not for local (offline) repos, right?  
I need a repo-system also for offline machines.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [link.](http://felix.apache.org/site/integrating-felix-with-netbeans.html)
It gives you a detailed step by step procedure for integrating Felix with NetBeans.

Comment: I think this document is just about *launching* Felix inside Netbeans to debug/profile it.